# Best way to search through an array to find peaks, without splitting it or creating new arrays, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

I have a working peak search function that takes an array as a parameter and then returns the peak value of that array. I need to find the main peak, and then the left peak and a right peak. I need to then be able to continue finding peaks. Meaning that, the user hits a button and every time they hit
the button, the array is passed in to find the next peak. For example

**arr = [1,5,25,7,8,3,34,8,9,9,91,7,3,7,8,4,1,39,0,3,7,8,14,2]**

Calling the peak search function on it, 91 is main peak, 39 is right peak, 34 is left peak. Now the button is hit again and right peak should be 14, and left peak should be 25. And so on, and so on, each time searching for the peak either to the left or to the right. My problem is that my initial array has around 500,000 values in it. Originally, I was splitting the array each time, so I'd have the main array of 500,000 values, then 2 more arrays of 250k or so each. Now I'm holding onto a million values, and that number only grows as I continue finding more and more peaks. I need to search the main array only, searching for the main peak, and then x amount of values to the left and x values to the right. I'm not sure if I'll need 2 seperate functions, or if I can just decrement from the peak and increment to get the two values. Or make a new peak search function with inputs
of the array, the start index, and the stop index and search from there. My peak search function is working correctly and returns the correct peaks when passed in an array.

This is my current, working peak search function

```
 function find_the_peaks(nums) {
      if (!nums.length) return -1; //break
      //else init variables to be used for specific points
      var left = 0;
      var right = nums.length - 1;
      var mid1 = 0;
      var mid2 = 0;
      //compare points to find where there is the greatest difference in change, finding the highest delta
      while (left < right) {
        mid1 = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        mid2 = mid1 + 1;
        if (nums[mid1] < nums[mid2]) {
          left = mid2;
        } else {
          right = mid1;
        }
      }
      return left;
    //return point with the greatest change, aka the next highest peak
    };
```

I do not think this is a duplicate because although there are other questions regarding peak searches, all of them doing multiple searches need you to split the array at a certain point.

One idea I had was finding every single peak and storing all of those in an array, from there find the peak as the highest value and then just move one to the left or right depending on which way the user wants. But I have no clue how I would do that.

Comment: How do you define peak? A value that greater than both the previous and the next one?

Comment: Yes, the highest peak would be the place where the delta is the highest between points. And then like you said for the remainder of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    function find_all_the_peaks(arr) {
    var peak;
        return arr.reduce(function(peaks, val, i) {
    if (arr[i+1] > arr[i]) {
        peak = arr[i+1];
    } else if ((arr[i+1] < arr[i]) && (typeof peak === 'number')) {
        peaks.push(peak);
        peak = undefined;
    }
        return peaks;
    }, []);
};
```

This returns just the list of peaks in array format.